# Android Studio : 'Instant Run' grayed out for all my projects

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

The 'Instant Run' button is grayed out for all my projects.

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you check instant run settings under Build, Execution, Deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
- Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
- Check the box next to Enable Instant Run.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/#disable-ir)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the first time you run your app on your device (every time you connect over USB, which you just connected), the Instant Run button is unavailable. Once you have run the app and your device is still connected, the Instant Run button becomes available.

There may also be a possibility that Instant Run is disabled in Android Studio's settings. You can enable that by:

1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog: On Windows or Linux, select
   File -> Settings from the menu bar. On Mac OSX, select Android Studio
   -> Preferences from the menu bar.
2. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
3. Un-check the box next to Restart activity on code changes.

Hope that helps.